# Convert 24bit image to 8bit in monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, imaging, bit-depth

We have an image processing windows application where we are using lead tools for converting and images from 24/48 bit images to 8 bit images.

As an experiment I'm porting the application to iPad using MonoTouch and C#, now the LeadTools components are incompatible with Monotouch. Is there any alternate I can use? if not how can I convert 24/48 bit images to 8 bit?

Comment: Are you interested in a monochromatic conversion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Apple's imaging tools here is where I would start:

1. Convert your raw bytes into a pixel format supported by the platform. See the Quartz 2D documentation on [supported pixel formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB).
   Note that iOS doesn't currently have a 24 or 48 bit format. However, if your 24 bit format is 8 bits per channel (RGB) you could add 8 bits of ignored alpha. (Alpha options are in MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGImageAlphaInfo)
2. Convert your raw bytes into a CGImage. Here is an example of how to do that

   ```
       var provider = new CGDataProvider(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       int bitsPerComponent = 8;
       int components = 4;
       int height = bytes.Length / components / width;
       int bitsPerPixel = components * bitsPerComponent;
       int bytesPerRow = components * width;   // Tip:  When you create a bitmap graphics context, you’ll get the best performance if you make sure the data and bytesPerRow are 16-byte aligned.
       bool shouldInterpolate = false;
       var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
       var cgImage = new CGImage(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, 
                                 colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.Last, provider,
                                 null, shouldInterpolate, CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
   ```
3. Use a [Core Image Filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImag%E2%80%A6) to convert to Monochrome

   ```
       var mono = new CIColorMonochrome
       {
           Color = CIColor.FromRgb(1, 1, 1),
           Intensity = 1.0f,
           Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(image)
       };
       CIImage output = mono.OutputImage;
       var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
       var renderedImage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
   ```
4. Finally you can retrieve the raw bytes of that image by drawing into a CGBitmapContext constructed according to your desired parameters.

I suspect this pipeline could be optimized, but it is a place to start. I'd be interested to hear what you end up with.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option will be to do native calls to the LeadTools libraries - any image manipulation in C# that I can think of is going to rely on components like GDI+ and the System.Drawing namespace which isn't supported by monotouch.

You can call native objective-C code from your monotouch project by creating a Binding project - http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

This should allow you to port your code in a way that will produce the exact same image/quality/format without really having to rework your current conversion code.